# Access to API through Azure API Management without setting Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Is there a way to create a API which does not require the caller to pass in the Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key without having to create a separate product and un-checking the Require subscription checkbox. What I want is within the same product to have some APIs which require the Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key to be passed in and some APIs which can be called without passing the Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key in the request header.

Comment: i might be wrong, but as far as I recall it is not possible to get rid of ocp-apim-subscription-key, but it was over a year ago, i don't remember my exact findings

Answer (score 1):

We cannot achieve it without un-checking the Require subscription checkbox.

I have been working around APIM these days, and as per my understanding we need to create a new Product, which doesnot require subscription.

And Ideally we should write some throttling policies to all open products. Lower rate limit for guest, and higher limit for the users with subscription key.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid a product is either bound to a subscription or not. You cannot mix both into the same product.

That being said, it is possible to implement a similar "subscription key" within your APIM policy for example. But, obviously, you would need to custom build it yourself.